# Count the number of mixes of the card to get come back to origin

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> Mix a deck of 52 cards by placing them in two parts and take alternate cards from both stacks. Use the cycle notation to show that it only takes 8 mixes to come back to the origin.

Since we want to come back to the origin then the permutation must be even, right? But how shall I get the cycle notation of the permutation?

I need help to start with the exercise (I prefer hints).

Comment: The exercise should really specify which of the two stacks you use for the bottom card.  As it turns out, you only get 8 mixes if you do it a certain way.

Comment: I did copy paste the exercise, so this is the only information. @Goos

Comment: OK.  But it isn't enough information.  It matters whether the top and bottom cards stay on top and bottom, or whether they move by one.

Comment: In fact, if you shuffle the other way (card 0 goes to card 1, card 1 to card 3, and so on) it takes 52 shuffles instead of 8.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** number the cards 0 to 51.

- Card 0 becomes card 0.
- Card 1 becomes card 2.
- Card 2 becomes card 4.
- Card 3 becomes card 6.
- $\cdots$
- Card 26 becomes card 1.
- Card 27 becomes card 3.
- $\cdots$

Try working mod $n$ for some $n$.

Comment: thanks. i will try to solve it with your hint.